# textual substitution in an html template by ${varName} notation

Tags: javascript, dojo, serverside-javascript, shorthand

so I was looking at a project and I noted that they had a templating system set up in html files, and I am not too familiar with the whole concept...But when I started browsing the code I was seeing things like: ${varName} which upon execution were being substituted for names out of an nls file which I assume is intended to allow for multiple languages.

I know for a fact that the templating file does not get parsed by a php engine, so I am thinking that maybe the syntax is some type of shorthand for server-side javascript. Which has me intrigued, does anyone have any ideas as to how they are accomplishing this substitution? I cant seem to find info on this in any google search I could think of, so any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Agree with mu.  This could also be a client-side template, such as http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: @anon- ah ok, I will look into if it is in fact client side. @mu - the project is not public yet, so name wouldn't give too much info. I could post a code snippet if that would help, but I doubt it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at code which extends dijit._Templated and references a file or an inline string with this syntax, it's being parsed client side.  The references are variable names on the widget JS object, which can be set up to point at strings from a localized string bundle with dojo.i18n